# How many references to time are there in the first 10 minutes of Back to the Future?

Tags: back-to-the-future

I just have to list how many times the references to TIME in the first ten minutes of *Back to the Future*. How many are there?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should take the [tour] to find out more about the site and what kind of questions are considered appropriate.  This seems like the kind of question you could answer yourself with a DVD and 10 minutes, so people will likely not want to do your basic research for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework/trivia question.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because I think the question meets the criteria of "a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer", and because I think the answer could turn out to be particularly interesting if there are references that people miss on a casual viewing.  Jose, what references did you see in the first 10 minutes?  Are there any in particular that you are not sure about?

Comment: @Möoz - Trivia questions aren't off-topic here. You must be mistaking us for Movies:SE

Comment: @Möoz - Homework questions aren't off-topic here either; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/how-do-we-feel-about-homework-questions

Comment: @Valorum Moi? Mistake this trash heap for the *other* trash heap? How preposterous.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from 00:00 to 10.00

**1)** Ticking sound heard over BttF logo
**1.5)** Approx 15 clocks in the Doc's room (of various types include mechanical, pendulum and electronic), a [Heath-Robinsonesque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) can opener, a timer toaster oven and a timer coffee maker
**2)** Satirical picture of [Harold Lloyd holding onto a clock hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsQ5O.jpg)
**3)** News broadcast informs us that it's 1985.
**4)** Call from the doc asking Marty to be at the mall for 1:15
**4.5)** Doc advises us that the chiming clocks are wrong and that it's 8.25 (Late for school)
**5)** Marty passes some parking meters.
**6)** Clock outside Mayor Goldie Wilson's campaign offices
**7)** Strickland is looking for Marty to give him a "tardy" slip.
**8)** Marty blames the doc for his clocks being late.
**9)** Strickland gives Marty his well-earned warning for being late.
**10)** Marty asserts that "*history is gonna change*".
**11)** Clock outside Goodwill store.
**12)** Marty is worried that record execs will tell him he's "*...got no future*"
**13)** 'Save the Clock Tower' demonstration in background
**14)** Ruined clock tower in the background.
**15)** More parking meters.